# hbase fuzzy/filter list matching for REST from shell

Tags: rest, hadoop, hbase, stargate

I am trying to formulate some RESTful calls to return specific data from a hbase table using fuzzy logic OR multiple filters (filterList). My **rowkey** is made up of '**BatchId** + **UserId** + **Timestamp**' + '**ModelId**', as an example i would like to be able to find all people where rowkey contains UserId of xyz' & 'ModelId' of 'yxz' (irrespective of BatchId & Timestamp values).

I've had no luck replicating fuzzy filters from the shell, as a last resort i'm attempting to use a filter list (multiple filters) to filter on each of the columns individually (this comes at a performance cost, which i can accept).

With regards the filter list, when trying to filter on the RK itself, i am not sure what value to pass for qualifier & column family too or the syntax for adding more than one filter, any help greatly appreciated.

Find my curl command & the args file contents for filterlist below.

CURL: 
**curl -vi -X PUT -H "Content-Type:text/xml" -d @args.xml "host-rest-machine-address/namespace:table/scanner"**

ARGS.XML:

```
<Scanner batch ="1024">

<filter>

{

    "type": "FilterList",

    "op": "MUST_PASS_ONE",

    "filters": [{

        "type": "FilterList",

        "op": "MUST_PASS_ALL",

        "filters": [{

            "type": "FamilyFilter",

            "op": "EQUAL",

            "comparator": {

                "type": "BinaryComparator",

                "value": "Y2Yx"

            }

        }, {

            "type": "QualifierFilter",

            "op": "EQUAL",

            "comparator": {

                "type": "BinaryComparator",

                "value": "cm93S2V5"

            }

        }, {

            "type": "RowFilter",

            "op": "EQUAL",

            "comparator": {

                "type": "BinaryComparator",

                "value": "MjAwMDAyMDE4OTM3Mw=="

            }

        }]

    }]

}

</filter>

</Scanner>
```

**My column family: cf1** (not sure if this is applicable when searching against row key?)
**Qualifier: column name** in hbase table (also unsure of how to refer to rowkey here - have tried row, rowkey, my sql alias on import with no luck)
Value: value to filter on for given column/table

Note - all values being passed are base_64 encoded

Thanks in advance